# Weld (JSR-299) and JBoss AS 5.1 possible?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss5.x, jboss-weld

Has anybody successfully implemented Weld with a JBoss AS 5.1 project?  I'm using EJB3.1, and I'm disappointed with the injection limitations (can't call from POJO, lookups from JNDI)

BUT on their site, JBoss 5.x isn't listed as a tested platform.

http://seamframework.org/Weld

Supported platforms
Weld has been tested on the following platforms:

```
JBoss Application Server 7
JBoss Application Server 6
GlassFish V3.x
Apache Tomcat 6 & 7
Jetty 6.1 & 7.x
Java SE 5.0+
```

Anyone have success with this?

Comment: Just wondering, how are you using EJB 3.1 with JBoss AS 5.1?

Comment: good point.  EJB 3.0 is bundled with JBoss AS 5.1, so I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDI support is only available OOTB in AS6 and above.  If you want, you can embed Weld in your ear or war file.  but it won't have EJB integration

Comment: What does "won't have EJB integration" mean? What do we lose? If I just want DI in non-EJB code that may be called by the implementation of an EJB endpoint is that possible?